# How do I uninstall BManager?

Tags: executable

How do I uninstall BManager from my computer? I have an empty box on my desk top that will not close. Due to the fact the box will not close, I can't delete BManager.

Comment: You forgot to include the most important part: how did you install it? if apt-get `apt-get remove` can be done from control-alt-f1 terminal. If manual you need to look at the directory and try to find an uninstall script. Every install will have a method to install...

Comment: @Rinzwind I think you mean every install will have a method to uninstall...

Answer (score -1):

First I uninstalled from the control panel. It still would not go away even though it did not show up in the program list.

Next I opened Task Manager and closed BManager in the task manager, then rebooted computer. It no longer opened at start up. Don't know if it is totally gone but it is no longer bothering me.